# Asp.net Dynamic data multiple relational entities on single page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

How to create form out of multiple relational entities with Asp.net dynamic data.

E.g. I have a customer table associated with address master. (1 -> 0.1)

I want to show both these entities to a single page while create and editing customer.

How could I achieve this with dynamic data scaffolding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should customize *Insert.aspx* and *Edit.aspx* page templates [How to: Customize the Layout of an Individual Table By Using a Custom Page Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488537%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in order to place on the custom page additional (GridView or FormView) control for showing another entity.

The next step is the following. Consider example of editing customer.

**~/DynamicData/CustomPages/Customer/Edit.aspx** (partially):

```
<%-- FormView with Customer entity --%>

<asp:FormView 
    ID="FormViewEditCustomer" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="EditCustomerDataSource" 
    DefaultMode="Edit"
    OnItemCommand="FormViewEditCustomer_ItemCommand"
    OnItemDeleted="FormViewEditCustomer_ItemDeleted" 
    RenderOuterTable="false">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <table id="editTable" class="table-edit" cellpadding="6">
            <asp:DynamicEntity runat="server" Mode="Edit" />
        </table>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:EntityDataSource 
    ID="EditCustomerDataSource" 
    runat="server" 
    EnableUpdate="true" 
    EnableDelete="true" 
    OnUpdated="EditCustomerDataSource_Updated"
    OnSelected="EditCustomerDataSource_Selected"/>
<asp:QueryExtender 
    ID="EditCustomerQueryExtender"
    TargetControlID="EditCustomerDataSource" 
    runat="server">
    <asp:DynamicRouteExpression />
</asp:QueryExtender>
```

**GridView** with *Address* entity - **Version 1 with QueryExtender and DynamicRouteExpression**

```
<%-- GridView with Address entity - Version 1 with DynamicRouteExpression --%>

<asp:GridView 
    ID="GridViewAddress" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AddressDataSource"
    AllowPaging="true" 
    AllowSorting="false" 
    PageSize="10" 
    CssClass="table-list" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:EntityDataSource 
    ID="AddressDataSource" 
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=Entities" 
    DefaultContainerName="Entities"
    EntitySetName="Address" />
<asp:QueryExtender 
    ID="AddressQueryExtender" 
    TargetControlID="AddressDataSource"
    runat="server">
    <asp:DynamicRouteExpression ColumnName="Customer_Id" />
</asp:QueryExtender>
```

In **Version 1** we use a special type of data source expression **DynamicRouteExpression**. At runtime, this object extracts the values of the primary key columns from the **URL** and modifies the query generated by the **AddressDataSource** to include appropriate filter criteria.

It must be noted that the table (entity) **Address** must include column name **Customer_Id**(and **NOT** for example **Address_Customer_Id**), otherwise **GridViewAddress** will include all addresses.

---

**GridView** with *Address* entity - **Version 2 with QueryExtender with CustomExpression and OnQuerying** is more powerful version

```
<%-- GridView with Address entity - Version 2 with QueryExtender with CustomExpression and OnQuerying --%>

<asp:GridView 
    ID="GridViewAddress" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AddressDataSource"
    AllowPaging="true" 
    AllowSorting="false" 
    PageSize="10" 
    CssClass="table-list" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:EntityDataSource 
    ID="AddressDataSource" 
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=Entities" 
    DefaultContainerName="Entities"
    EntitySetName="Address" />
<asp:QueryExtender 
    ID="AddressQueryExtender" 
    TargetControlID="AddressDataSource"
    runat="server">
    <asp:CustomExpression 
        OnQuerying="AddressQueryExtender_Querying" />
</asp:QueryExtender>
```

In order to implement **Version 2** we should use, first of all, *Selected* event of **EditCustomerDataSource** in order to get **Customer_Id** from *EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs*, that provides data for the *Selected* event, then we can use **CustomExpression**  that is used by the **QueryExtender** control. The custom expression calls the **AddressQueryExtender_Querying** method, where we should use a custom LINQ expression and the results of the filtering operation (by **Customer_Id** from *EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs*) will be displayed in a **GridViewAddress**.

Code-behind:

**~/DynamicData/CustomPages/Customer/Edit.aspx.cs** (partially):

```
protected int customerId;

protected void EditCustomerDataSource_Selected(object sender, EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customerItem = e.Results.Cast<Customer>();
    foreach (Customer c in customerItem)
    {
        customerId = c.Customer_Id;
    }
}

protected void AddressQueryExtender_Querying(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Expressions.CustomExpressionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Query = (from a in e.Query.Cast<Address>()
               where a.Customer_Id == customerId
               select a);
}
```

More detailed information and explanations you can find from the book **ASP.NET Dynamic Data Unleashed**.