# .NET Dynamic Data: Edit linked entities directly in the form

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-dynamic-data

Suppose I have the following entities in my model (this is a kind of presudo-code, but I think it's enough to understand):

```
Team {
  string Name
  string City
  List<Player> Players
}

Player {
  string Name
  string Surname
  int Number
}
```

I'm using ASP.NET Dynamic Data with Entity Framework ORM.

What I want to achieve is a form for editing both `Team` info and its list of `Players`, creating them right on the same page. I wonder something like including `Player's` edit view into the form for each player I add to the team.

I'm just arrived into DynamicData's world, so please forgive me if I missed a beginner guide about it.

Thanks

Comment: I would like to draw your attention to my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452303/asp-net-dynamic-data-multiple-relational-entities-on-single-page/15883527