# Displaying data from two database tables on one page using Dynamic Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, dynamic-data

Hi can anyone help me with this. I am using dynamic data and have created a custom page which displays all orders within a database table. Once someone selects an order I would like it display all the individual items for that order. This data is stored in another table but within the same database. I found a very useful article on here [Asp.net Dynamic data multiple relational entities on single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452303/asp-net-dynamic-data-multiple-relational-entities-on-single-page) which I think gives me pretty much my answer but I am stuck where it comes to the part about implementing IEnumerable (I am trying to implement version 2 on the page).  I have done some reading on IEnumerable but I am really lost. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to create a new class. Can anyone help?

Here is the code I have so far:

HTML code:

```
<h2 class="DDSubHeader">Catering Request Orders</h2>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="DD">
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true"
                HeaderText="List of validation errors" CssClass="DDValidator" />
            <asp:DynamicValidator runat="server" ID="GridViewValidator" ControlToValidate="GridView1" Display="None" CssClass="DDValidator" />
            <asp:DynamicValidator runat="server" ID="FormViewValidator" ControlToValidate="FormView1" Display="None" CssClass="DDValidator" />

            <asp:QueryableFilterRepeater runat="server" ID="FilterRepeater">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' OnPreRender="Label_PreRender" />
                    <asp:DynamicFilter runat="server" ID="DynamicFilter" OnFilterChanged="DynamicFilter_FilterChanged" /><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:QueryableFilterRepeater>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" />
        </div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="GridDataSource" EnablePersistedSelection="True"
            AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" 
            OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging"
            OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated"
            OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" CssClass="DDGridView"
            RowStyle-CssClass="td" HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" CellPadding="6">

           <Columns>
           <%--<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DynamicHyperLink ID="DynamicHyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Details" />
            <a id="CategoryRouteID" runat="server" href= '<%# GetRouteInformation() %>'/>

               <%--                 <asp:DynamicHyperLink ID="DynamicHyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Details" />
                        <!-- Create action link to filter items that
                        belong to the same category -->
                         <a ID="CategoryRouteID" runat="server" href='<%# GetRouteInformation() %>'>
                        </a></asp:DynamicHyperLink>

            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>--%>

            <asp:DynamicField DataField="OrderNo" HeaderText="Order No" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="DisplayName" HeaderText="Display name" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="Email address" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="DeliveryDate" HeaderText="Delivery date" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="Site" HeaderText="Site" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="OrderProgress" HeaderText="Order progress" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="tblCateringOrdersDetailsItems" HeaderText="Item details" />
           </Columns>

            <HeaderStyle CssClass="th" />

            <PagerStyle CssClass="DDFooter" />        
            <RowStyle CssClass="td" />
            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="DDSelected" />
            <PagerTemplate>
                <asp:GridViewPager ID="GridViewPager1" runat="server" />
            </PagerTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                There are currently no items in this table.
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEDFF0" Font-Bold="True" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEDFF0" Font-Bold="True" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="GridDataSource" runat="server" EnableDelete="true" EnableUpdate="true" />

        <asp:QueryExtender ID="GridQueryExtender" TargetControlID="GridDataSource" runat="server">
            <asp:DynamicFilterExpression ControlID="FilterRepeater" />
        </asp:QueryExtender>

        <asp:Panel ID="DetailsPanel" runat="server">
            <br /><br />
            <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="DetailsDataSource" RenderOuterTable="false"
                OnPreRender="FormView1_PreRender" OnModeChanging="FormView1_ModeChanging" OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated"
                OnItemInserted="FormView1_ItemInserted" OnItemDeleted="FormView1_ItemDeleted" OnItemCommand="FormView1_ItemCommand">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table id="detailsTable" class="DDDetailsTable" cellpadding="6">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Order No</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="OrderNo" runat="server" DataField="OrderNo" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">User ID</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="UserID" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Display Name</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DisplayName" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Email Address</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="EmailAddress" runat="server" DataField="EmailAddress" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Project Code</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ProjectCode" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Event Description</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="EventDesc" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Delivery Date</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DeliveryDate" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Date Ordered</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DateOrdered" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Site</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Site" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Time</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Time" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Location</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Location" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Additional Information</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="AdditionalInfo" DataField="AdditionalInfo" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Item Costs</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="ItemCosts" DataField="ItemCosts" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">AdditionalCosts</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="AdditionalCosts" DataField="AdditionalCosts" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Total Costs</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="TotalCosts" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">More Information Required</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="MoreInformationRequired" UIHint="MultilineText" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Reason Rejected</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ReasonRejected" UIHint="MultilineText" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Order Progress</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="OrderProgress" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Imported Into Dream</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ImportedIntoDream" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">View Items</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl  runat="server" DataField="tblCateringOrdersDetailsItems" /></td>
                </tr>
                    <%--<asp:DynamicEntity ID="DynamicEntity1" runat="server" />--%>
                    <tr class="td">
                       <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                                OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");' />
                           <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CommandName="New" Text="New" />--%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                 <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Order No</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="OrderNo" runat="server" DataField="OrderNo" Mode="ReadOnly"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">User ID</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="UserID" Mode="ReadOnly"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Display Name</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DisplayName" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Email Address</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="EmailAddress" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Project Code</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ProjectCode" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Event Description</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="EventDesc" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Delivery Date</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DeliveryDate" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Date Ordered</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DateOrdered" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Site</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Site" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Time</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Time" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Location</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Location" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Additional Information</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="AdditionalInfo" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Item Costs</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="ItemCosts" DataField="ItemCosts" Mode="Edit" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Additional Costs</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="AdditionalCosts" DataField="AdditionalCosts" Mode="Edit" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Total Costs</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="TotalCosts" DataField="TotalCosts" Mode="Edit"  /></td>
                    <%--<td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCalculateTotalCosts" Text="Calculate total costs" CommandName="Calculate" /></td>--%>
               <%--   <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateOrder" runat="server" onclick="btnUpdateOrder_Click"
        Text="Update Order" />--%>
                </tr>                    

                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">More Information Required</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="MoreInformationRequired" Mode="Edit" UIHint="MultilineText" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Reason Rejected</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ReasonRejected" Mode="Edit" UIHint="MultilineText" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Order Progress</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="OrderProgress" Mode="Edit" UIHint="OrderProgressDropDown" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Imported Into Dream</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ImportedIntoDream" Mode="Edit" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">View Items</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="tblCateringOrdersDetailsItems" Mode="Edit" /></td>
                </tr>
                    <%--<asp:DynamicEntity ID="DynamicEntity2" runat="server" Mode="Edit" />--%>
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DynamicEntity ID="DynamicEntity3" runat="server" Mode="Insert" />
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton7" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>

            <asp:EntityDataSource ID="DetailsDataSource" runat="server" EnableDelete="true" EnableInsert="true" EnableUpdate="true" />

            <asp:QueryExtender ID="QueryExtender1" TargetControlID="DetailsDataSource" runat="server">
                <asp:ControlFilterExpression ControlID="GridView1" />
            </asp:QueryExtender>
        </asp:Panel>


        <%--code for details items --%>

        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PanelItemDetails">
           <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceItemDetails" EnablePersistedSelection="True"
                DataKeyNames="OrderNo"
            AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnDataBound="GridView2_DataBound" 
            OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanging"
            OnRowDeleted="GridView2_RowDeleted" OnRowUpdated="GridView2_RowUpdated"
            OnRowCreated="GridView2_RowCreated" CssClass="DDGridView"
            RowStyle-CssClass="td" HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" CellPadding="6">

            <Columns>
                <%--<asp:DynamicField DataField="tblCateringItemsDetail" HeaderText="Item" />--%>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Quantity" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalUnitCost" HeaderText="TotalUnitCost" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TotalUnitCost" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderNo" HeaderText="OrderNo" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="OrderNo" />
            </Columns>

            <HeaderStyle CssClass="th" />

            <PagerStyle CssClass="DDFooter" />        
            <RowStyle CssClass="td" />
            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="DDSelected" />
            <PagerTemplate>
                <asp:GridViewPager ID="GridViewPager1" runat="server" />
            </PagerTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                There are currently no items in this table.
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEDFF0" Font-Bold="True" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEDFF0" Font-Bold="True" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:QueryExtender ID="QueryExtender2" TargetControlID="EntityDataSourceItemDetails" runat="server">
                <asp:CustomExpression 
    OnQuerying="OrdersQueryExtender_Querying" />
        </asp:QueryExtender>

            <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceItemDetails" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="name=cateringEntities" 
                DefaultContainerName="cateringEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
                EntitySetName="vCateringOrdersAllDetails" 
                Select="it.[Description], it.[Quantity], it.[TotalUnitCost], it.[OrderNo]"   ORDERBY="it.OrderNo]" >                    
            </asp:EntityDataSource>

        </asp:Panel>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# code:

```
protected void SelectOrder_Selected(object sender, EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<OrderItems> orderItem = e.Results.Cast<Order>();
        foreach (Order o in orderItem)
        {
            customerId = c.Customer_Id;
        }
    }

     protected void OrderQueryExtender_Querying(object sender, system.Web.UI.WebControls.Expressions.CustomExpressionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Query = (from a in e.Query.Cast<Order>()
                   where a.OrderNo == orderNo
                   select a);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Claire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Nimit for your response. It was very useful. If it helps anyone else I found exactly what I was looking for at http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-4.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is as follows

1. First I display list of all orders selected in a grid view.
2. When user selects to see detail of any order i fire grid view row command event and pass order id as command argument.
3. Then in code behind i get order entity with the help of order id passed in step 2 and along with order entity i get order details and display it in second grid view.